# stack overflow when loading relationship

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, lombok

I have the following relationship:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
public class Room extends BasePersistable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String uid;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=true)
    private String fullName;

    @Column(nullable=true, length=500)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable=true)
    private String homepage;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String owner;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"repos", "members"})
    private Organization organization;
```

and

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
@JsonInclude(content=Include.NON_NULL)
public class Organization extends BasePersistable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7119760968529447945L;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private Integer uid;

    @Column
    private String avatar;

    @Column
    private String blog;

    @Column
    private String company;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    private String login;

    @Column(nullable=true)
    private String location;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="organization")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"users", "joined", "organization"})
    private List<Room> repos = new ArrayList<>();
```

when I load the rooms from a specific user, I get this error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.inkdrop.app.domain.models.Organization.hashCode(Organization.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.inkdrop.app.domain.models.Room.hashCode(Room.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.AbstractList.hashCode(AbstractList.java:541) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.Vector.hashCode(Vector.java:992) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.hashCode(IndirectList.java:504) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.inkdrop.app.domain.models.Organization.hashCode(Organization.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.inkdrop.app.domain.models.Room.hashCode(Room.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.AbstractList.hashCode(AbstractList.java:541) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.Vector.hashCode(Vector.java:992) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.hashCode(IndirectList.java:504) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.inkdrop.app.domain.models.Organization.hashCode(Organization.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.inkdrop.app.domain.models.Room.hashCode(Room.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.AbstractList.hashCode(AbstractList.java:541) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.Vector.hashCode(Vector.java:992) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList.hashCode(IndirectList.java:504) ~[org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.inkdrop.app.domain.models.Organization.hashCode(Organization.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.inkdrop.app.domain.models.Room.hashCode(Room.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
....
```

I'm not really sure if the problem is related to Eclipselink or something that Lombok made.

edit: I noticed that sometimes it does work (when I delete the whole database)

Comment: Since this is ocuring on a hashCode call, check the logic in your hashCode methods - they appear to be recursively or going through the entire object model.  You might not want to rely on calling hashCode on any collection attribute.

Comment: I'm using lombok, so I'm not really responsible for the implementation

Comment: Anyway, lombok has an option to exclude certain fields from the calculation, that did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `exclude` attribute to your `EqualsAndHashCode` annotation.
E.g., to exclude the `repos` collection from your Organization entity, use:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, exclude={"repos"})
```

before the constructor of your Organization class.

Also, if someone is reading this answer and happens to use Hibernate, I recommend using `Set` (instead of `List`) for your collections. Aside from avoiding the dreaded `MultipleBagFetchException`, `Set` allows you to have more than one eagerly loaded collection in your entity. It also allows you to load multiple collections using `[left] join fetch`, if you want to sometimes use lazy v.s. eager loading.